# passing an variables from django to jquery?

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete

I'm trying to make an array out of a text file My django/python code is

```
f = open('text file path here', 'r')
names = []
for line in f:
    names.append(line)
f.close()
return render_to_response('frontend.html', {'names'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then my frontend.html takes the array, names, and uses the data for autocomplete in a form whose id='status':

```
<script>

var names = {{ names }};

$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#status").autocomplete(names);
       });

</script>
```

Nothing happens in the field on frontend.html when I start typing someone's name. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post what the {{ names }} array looks like after it's been generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an url endpoint inside your `url.py` and in your views you can return a response with `names` in JSON and fetch them in your template using a getJSON call.

**View**

```
from django.utils import simplejson

def names(request):
   ..build your name collection
   data = simplejson.dumps(names)
   return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

**Template**

```
$.getJSON('/your_json_endpoint/names/', function(data) {
// data contains your names serialized

});
```

You need to set the endpoint in your URLConf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/

See here for a complete example: http://mitchfournier.com/2011/06/06/getting-started-with-ajax-in-django-a-simple-jquery-approach/

Comment: how does getJSON know to look for `names`? is that what `'ajax/test.json'` is for?

Comment: Sorry iPad here I'm building the answer piece by piece...It's the URL of your localhost endpoint.

Comment: It's the URL you choose and set in your `url.py`. I added a link to an updated blog with an example as further help.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
return render_to_response('frontend.html', {'names'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

-- where do you see it passing the *value* of 'names'? You want:

```
return render_to_response('frontend.html', {'names': names}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Actually, your code isn't even valid python syntax so I suspect an error in your copypasting...